# Minting parent tokens from child contract

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, inheritance

Is it possible to mint ERC20 tokens that are created in a parent contract, from a child contract? If so how is it implemented?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about access control and an appropriate function to call.

In the parent contract, you will need a mint or `issueTokens()` function (to avoid name conflict/confusion).

```
function issueTokens(who, quantity) external onlyChildren ... { ... }
```

Notice the `onlyChildren` modifier. That would control access so only trusted contracts are allowed to call the function.

Something like ...

```
modifier onlyChildren {
  require( isChild[msg.sender], "don't know you" );
  _;
}
```

Relies on a mapping that knows which contracts to trust.

```
mapping(address => bool) public isChild;
```

That relies on keeping track of deployed contracts:

```
Child child = new Child();
isChild[address(child)] = true;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So lets say I created mintNewToken function with proper checks and modifiers. In child contract, i'd call PARENTCONTRACT.mintNewToken(who, amount)?

Comment: Correct. The child would use an interface and it would know who the parent is because it's `msg.sender` in the `constructor` context. So, roughly `ParentInterface(myParent).doSomething()`

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer ;-)